# Ayuda en modulo de programacion y incrementacio de variable

Tags: c#

quiero hacer un programa que introduzca una serie de notas y una vez esto en otra parte en un modulo que me sume +1 por cada nota suspendida y me muestre el numero de gente que suspendio, una vez insertadas todas las notas.

Me cuenta solo con la ultima nota y nose como hacer para que tenga en cuenta el resto...

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Notas();
        }

```
    static void Notas()
    {
        int[] notas = new int[10];
        int incremento = 0;
        int nota = 0;

        while (incremento < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa un numero entre 0 i 10");
            nota = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (nota < 0 || nota > 10)
                Console.WriteLine("El numero no es un valor correcto");
            else
                notas[incremento] = nota;
            incremento++;
        }
        Calculos(nota);
    }

    static void Calculos(int nota)
    {
        int suspe = 0;

        if (nota < 5)
        {
            suspe++;
            Console.WriteLine("Han suspendido {0}", suspe);
        }

        /*else if (nota <= 5)
        {
            if (nota == 5)
                Console.WriteLine("suficientes son {0}");
            else if (nota == 6 || nota == 7)
                Console.WriteLine(" bien son {0}");
            else if (nota == 8 || nota == 9)
                Console.WriteLine(" notables son {0}");
            else if (nota == 10)
                Console.WriteLine(" execl·lentes son {0}");
        }*/

    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu funcion calculos, solo recibe la ultima nota. tal vez querias pasarle int[] notas y luego iterar por ese array?

Comment: y hay otro bug en tu codigo, dentro de la funcion Notas, si uno ingresa una nota incorrecta, la variable incremento se incrementa igual

Comment: Tu problema esta dado porque llamas a Calculo 1 sola vez y le pasas la ultima nota, si en vez de hacer eso pasas el arreglo de las notas, y lo recorres, entonces tu programa funcionaria.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aqui te dejo mi solución, al final lo que hice fue crear 4 variables dentro de la función calculo que es la ke va a contener los contadores de las diferentes notas, puedes usar una arreglo si te sientes mas cómodo. Declare **static** notas para no tener que pasarselo a la función Notas, ya que desde ahí es que llamas a **Calculo** y en esta última lo necesitas para iterar e ir contando.

```
static int[] notas;

static void Main(string[] args) {
    notas = new int[10];
    Notas(); 
}

static void Notas()
{        
    int incremento = 0;
    int nota = 0;

    while (incremento < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa un numero entre 0 y 10");
        nota = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (nota < 0 || nota > 10)
            Console.WriteLine("El numero no es un valor correcto");
        else
            notas[incremento++] = nota;
    }
    Calculos(notas);
}

static void Calculos(int[] notas)
{
    int suspe = 0;
    int suficiente = 0;
    int bien = 0;
    int notables = 0;       
    foreach(int nota in notas){
        if (nota < 5)
        {
            suspe++;                
        }
        else 
        {
            switch(nota){
                case 5: 
                    suficiente++;
                    break;
                case 6: 
                case 7: 
                    bien++;
                    break;
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    notables++;
                    break;
                default:
                    excelente++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("suficientes son {0}", suficiente);
    Console.WriteLine("bien son {0}", bien);
    Console.WriteLine("notables son {0}", notables);
    Console.WriteLine("excelente son {0}", notas.length-suficiente-bien-notables-suspe);
}
```